# Strange IndexOutOfBoundsException when accessing SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Crash log I received today:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.my.app/org.my.app.WorkoutActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 0
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2343)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2395)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600 (ActivityThread.java:162)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1364)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5392)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:525)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:833)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:600)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)

Caused by java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 0
java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException (ArrayList.java:251)
java.util.ArrayList.get (ArrayList.java:304)
org.my.app.DataManager.isPreviousMarathonAvailable (DataManager.java)
org.my.app.WorkoutActivity.onCreate (WorkoutActivity.java)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5122)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1084)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2307)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2395)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600 (ActivityThread.java:162)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1364)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5392)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:525)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:833)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:600)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

There is code of my methods (in DataManager class):

```
static boolean isPreviousMarathonAvailable(Context context)
{
    boolean isCDMode = getIsCDMode(context);
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("marathon", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.contains(isCDMode?"cdSave":"abSave");
}

static boolean getIsCDMode(Context context)
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getBoolean("isCD",false);
}
```

I don't understand how I can get IndexOutOfBoundsException in this code. This stack trace means that it happens deeper than in my method? I googled this problem (shared preferences and index out of bounds exception), and get this [link](http://spy01.com/news/2015/10/23/bug-related-to-shared-preferences-and-arrayoutofbounds-exception/), but don't understand situation at all. Also I know that user with this crash have Android 4.2.2 HTC Desire 210 dual sim. So, the question is: where this crash happened, this is my bad code or some Android internal bug? I don't have same crashes now, only one crash at one device.

Comment: That stack trace hardly seems possible. It implies that `isPreviousMarathonAvailable()`, directly, is calling `get()` on an `ArrayList`. You're not calling `get()` on anything. Are you sure that the app on this device matches this code? For example, might this device be running some old version of your app?

Comment: Yes. This crash received 26 Nov 2016, 19:17:26 (UTC I think). Firebase tells that is last version (27 in my case). And I have correct mapping.txt file uploaded, from ver. 27 build output to ver. 27 firebase option. Strange thing that there is no line numbers in this stack trace. I already wrote to Google (may be it really some bug there and it is wrong stack), but there is no answer right now.